# Close a particular JFrame embedded in a main JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a main JFrame which has other JFrames embedded to it which opens up on clicking the buttons on the main JFrame. The embedded JFrame has the following codes to close:

```
 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
{
System.exit(0);
}
```

but the problem is once i close the embedded JFrame the main JFrame also closes with it. I want only the embedded JFrame to close. can anyone help me out with this? Secondly, is

```
   this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

or

```
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
  {
    System.exit(0);
  }
```

better to close a frame?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: thanks! JInternalFrame would be the best to implement in this case?

Comment: Well, 'it depends' on what this app. is!  What is it, and what is it currently putting in the multiple frames?  Different documents for view/edit?  Different movies?  Different news feeds? ..

Comment: Well, I am trying to make an app where socket programming is being used. I am trying to embed other Frames which include chat, voice call, file sharing and remote desktop into the main frame.

Answer (score 2):

For closing  embedded JFrame use `dispose()`  function.

```
 public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
{
    dispose();
}
```

OR use

```
this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
```

`dispose()`

> Releases all of the native screen resources used by this Window, its
>   subcomponents, and all of its owned children. That is, the resources
>   for these Components will be destroyed, any memory they consume will
>   be returned to the OS, and they will be marked as undisplayable.
>
> The Window and its subcomponents can be made displayable again by
>   rebuilding the native resources with a subsequent call to pack or
>   show. The states of the recreated Window and its subcomponents will be
>   identical to the states of these objects at the point where the Window
>   was disposed (not accounting for additional modifications between
>   those actions).

**Note**:

> When the last displayable window within the Java virtual machine (VM)
>   is disposed of, the VM may terminate.

Comment: sorry, but it isn't at all closing on using dispose().

Comment: You mean to say the frame is not closing down using `dispose()` ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7143398/418556) for a short demo. of `DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE` using 3 frames.